# Trying to create .ear file. but the structure inside the ear is not as expected

Tags: linux, jakarta-ee

Hi i am trying to create a .ear file on a linux machine.
All the jars and other files are present in a particular folder.
I am trying to zip the  folder into .ear using the below command

```
      jar -cvf spa_2014120802.ear /workpoint/tbrtb/domains/WL1RTB1/gbierna/shaik/
```

Actual structure:
META-INF
   workpoint
    tbrtb
        domains
           WL1RTB1
                gbierna
                    shaik
                        lib
                        META-INF
                        properties

The  expected structure is 
lib
META-INF
properties

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

you should use the -C option to set the basedir:

```
jar cvf spa_2012120802.ear -C /workpoint/tbrtb/domains/WL1RTB1/gbierna/shaik/ .
```